# Google maps Markers are not refreshed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, dom-events

I am making a google maps app in react using the native google maps API. I have a main component (app.js), a map (map.js) and InfoWindowD (InfoWindowD.js)

My `<select onChange>...</select>` in InfoWindowD component calls `UpdateShowMarkers()` in App(app.js) and there I update my `state showMarkers`. The state gets updated but the Markers in my map doesn't (on load markers are filtered and just the matching will be created). Then this State is updated but nothing hapens. I cannot figure out what to do it.

I will apreciate any help.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Map from './map';
import Test from './test';
import InfoWindowD from './InfoWindowD'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  //  this.child = React.createRef();
  }
  state= {
      markers:
          [ {
            name: 'Стадион «Нижний Новгород»',
            lat: 56.337498,
            lng: 43.963386,
            venueId: '555eed18498e3451c8bf5765',
            type:'Sport'},
           {
            name: 'Большая Покровская улица',
            lat: 56.317676,
            lng: 43.995474,
            venueId: '4bd322019854d13ae2f1fc4d',
            type:'Entertaiment'},
           {
            name: 'Теннис Парк',
            lat: 56.292484,
            lng: 43.974676,
            venueId: '54a6a2a6498ee573efdc4234',
            type: 'Cafe'}
        ],
        showMarkers: 'Sport'
  }

//update showMarkers state
  updateShowMarkers = (placeType) => {

    console.log('updating the state showMarkers with value: ' + placeType)
  //  this.child.current.filterr(); this doesnt work
    this.setState({showMarkers: placeType})
  }

  ejecutar = () => {
    console.log('ejecutando')
  //  marker.setMap(null);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InfoWindowD markers={this.state.markers} UpdateShowMarkers={this.updateShowMarkers} showMarkers={this.state.showMarkers} filterMarkers={this.filterMarkers} ejecutar={this.ejecutar} />
<Test />

        <Map
        //ref={this.child}
          id="CenterNN"
          options={{
            center: { lat: 56.327114, lng: 44.005632 },
            zoom: 13
          }}


          onMapLoad={map => {
            var markerDetails = this.state.markers;
            for(var i = 0; i < markerDetails.length; i++ ) {
              //console.log('loop ' + i)

              var contentString = '<div>'+
                  '<p>Information is loading</p>'+
                  '</div>';

              var infoWindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
              });

            var position = new window.google.maps.LatLng(markerDetails[i].lat, markerDetails[i].lng);
console.log('a: ' + this.state.showMarkers + ' b: '+markerDetails[i].type)

            if( this.state.showMarkers === markerDetails[i].type ) {
            var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
              position: position,
            //  map: map, //set the markers in the map. below it was replaced
              title: markerDetails[i].name
            });

            // add markers to the map
            console.log('setting marker ' + markerDetails[i].type)
              marker.setMap(map);
          //  }
            console.log('continue the loop with ' + markerDetails[i].type)
            // else if(this.state.showMarkers === 'deleteall') {
            //   marker.setMap(null);
            // }


            //to remove markers from map use the next line
            //marker.setMap(null);
            var e;
            var filterMarkers = (e) => {
              console.log('filtering markers')
            //  marker.setMap(null);
            }
            var filterr = () => {
              console.log('filtering markers')
            }

            var venueInfo;
            var attractionTitle;
                  //  This request is not premium and is almost not limited to make tests per day
                    var foursquareVenue = (venueCode) => {
                      fetch(`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/${venueCode}/likes?client_id=CID&client_secret=CSECRET&v=20180818`)
                           .then((result) =>
                              result.json()
                           )
                           .then(parsedJSON =>
                                 (this.setState({attractions: parsedJSON.response}))
                            )
                            .then( ()=>
                              infoWindow.setContent(`<div><h2>${attractionTitle}</h2>
                                 Likes: ${getAttractionLikes()}<br>
                                 </div>`)
                               )
                           .catch((error) =>
                               console.log('There was a problem:' + error)
                           );
                    }



                    //this function can access the parent state
                    var getVenueDescription = () => {
                       if(!this.state.attractions.venue.description) {
                          return ('Description is not available for this place')
                       }
                       else{
                         return ( this.state.attractions.venue.description)
                       }
                    }
                    var getAttractionType = () => {
                      return ( this.state.attractions.venue.categories[0].name )
                    }
                    var getAttractionRating = () => {
                      return ( this.state.attractions.venue.rating )
                    }
                    var getAttractionAddress = () => {
                      return ( this.state.attractions.venue.location.address )
                    }
                    var getAttractionLikes = () => {
                      return ( this.state.attractions.likes.count )
                    }

                    // Allow each marker to have an info window
                    window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, ) {

                        return function() {
                           attractionTitle= markerDetails[i].name;
                          var uniCode= markerDetails[i].venueId;
                          //ejecutar la funcion foursquareVenue y pasarle una variable clave para buscar el venue necesitado
                          {foursquareVenue(markerDetails[i].venueId, attractionTitle)}

                           infoWindow.open(map, marker)

                        }
                    })(marker, i));

            }
          } // ends if from line 110
          }
        }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**map.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import InfoWindowD from './InfoWindowD'

const styles = {
  width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'absolute',
}



class Map extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onScriptLoad = this.onScriptLoad.bind(this)
  }

  onScriptLoad() {
    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById(this.props.id),
      this.props.options);
    this.props.onMapLoad(map)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.google) {
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.src = `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDyeZwrmykBXkG_FkJY6kPthSpdidMpFiM`;
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
      //We cannot access google.maps until it's finished loading
      s.addEventListener('load', e => {
        this.onScriptLoad()
      })
    } else {
      this.onScriptLoad()
    }

  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div state= {this.state} style={styles} id={this.props.id} />
    );
  }
}

export default Map
//based on http://cuneyt.aliustaoglu.biz/en/using-google-maps-in-react-without-custom-libraries/
```

**InfoWindow.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import Info from './Info'

const styles = {
    position: 'inherit', backgroundColor: 'white',
}

function InfoWindowD(props) {


  const { markers, infoWindow, filterMarkers, initialMarkers, ejecutar, map, newValue, updateShowMarkers, showMarkers } = props;

  props.markers.map((myMarker) => {
    if(myMarker.type === props.showMarkers) {
      console.log('inside ' + myMarker.name)
    }
    console.log('with map ' + myMarker.name)
  })
  return (
    <div style={styles}>
      <div>
        <Info newValue={props.newValue} />{props.showMarkers}
        <div />
        <div className="content">
        <h3>Attractions type</h3>
          <select defaultValue="all" onChange={(event)=>{props.UpdateShowMarkers(event.target.value), props.ejecutar(); }} >
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="deleteall">deleteall</option>
            { props.markers.map((place) => {
              return <option value={place.type}>{place.type}</option>
            })
            }
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default InfoWindowD;
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Hi Angel. I would suggest if you're learning maps without any hard deadline. You should have a look on react-google-maps. It is component based and more structured. Let me know if you need with this.

Comment: It looks like the `onMapLoad` function is only getting called from `componentDidMount` or `onScriptLoad`, both of which would only call `onMapLoad` once. I think that even though you are setting your state, your `onMapLoad` function is not getting called to update the markers on the map. If this is the case, you could try calling `onMapLoad` in `componentDidUpdate` of your `Map` component and passing the markers in as a prop. That may cause excessive heavy work to be done with a lot of calls to `onMapLoad` and it may be worth looking into a library like Sakhi noted.

Comment: Thanks Sakhi and Tyler,

sadly there is a deadline and I cannot switch to react-google-maps. Maybe I can move my method to update the state from app.js to map.js and from there it will get updated. Bud my markers are created in App.js, so I should move them too? I don't know :-( let's see. 
In any case thanks!